# Perl regex expression

Tags: perl, regex

I have the following string produced by a server log file.  I am using Simple Event Correlator (which uses perl regex) to manipulate lines:

```
18:37:31 643.65.123.123 []sent /home/mydomain/public_html/court-954fdw/Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg 226 court-954fdw@mydomain.com 256
```

and I have been successful in using perl regex to successfully extract 
the user who logs in with the following pattern.

**NOTE:** the values that SEC uses are extracted from the data contained in the parenthesis:

```
pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/(.*)\/(.*)
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in parsing out just the file name which in this case would be: `Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg`.

Currently the existing pattern I use pulls out the entire string:

```
Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg 226 court-954fdw@mydomain.com 256
```

which I don't want. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use:

```
pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/(.*)\/(\S+).*
```

This should extract out all but whitespace characters for the last capturing match, and leave the rest for the non-capturing match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following:

```
pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/(.*?)\/\(.* ?)\S*.*$
```

For more explicit non-greedy matching. Your result will now be in $2. This assumes that you can't hard-code anything below public_html. This does leave a trailing space.

Comment: Regex is invalid due to erroneous escaping of 3rd parenthesis. Not able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers assumes no whitespace in filename, a rather risky assumption. A safer bet is to assume no slashes in filename, as that is illegal in linux:

```
pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+) [0-9]+ \S+@\S+ [0-9]+$
```

Tested at https://regex101.com/